# jquery - change link href after clicked on

Tags: jquery

I want to change the href of a link after I click on it:

```
$('#mylink').click(function() {
    // do something
    $('#mylink').attr('href', 'newURL.php');
    });

<a href=# id=mylink>click</a>
```

i would assume this would work, but when I click on it, it redirects to new page.

How can I make it change the href after the user has finished clicking?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: if you add preventDefault, the new link also won't work

Comment: @mplungjan the preventDefault answers OPs question, my answer fixes the comment your putting on everyone else's answers. I'm not understanding why you're going on a serial downvote spree

Comment: Please explain WHAT you are trying to achieve instead of posting an X/Y problem. WHY do you want to change the HREF and if you need the page to change anyway you do not need to change the href, just change the location

Comment: @AndyHolmes I am not. I vote the SAME answer down 4 times :)

Comment: @mplungjan fair point

Comment: Anyway, removed my downvote - am still not happy with OP's lack of specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('#mylink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#mylink').attr('href', 'newURL.php');
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

The window.location will take the new url and direct you to it.

*edit*

As mplungjan has said in the comments, you can simplify this further:

```
$('#mylink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    window.location.href = 'newURL.php';
});
```

So you don't need to set the href attr directly, you could skip that and just utilise the `window.location.href` directly

Comment: Why? What will that do if the page disappears

Comment: Why downvote it? Your comment makes no sense

Comment: This helped me find a solution thanks, i added an if condition to check the current href, and redirected if it wasn't "#"

Comment: @user1022585 please tell us what you wanted to happen?

Comment: No problem @user1022585 - Please accept as it helped guide you :)

Comment: Will as soon as site lets me :)

Comment: Anyway, removed my downvote - still do not think the OP had given use a proper explanation of the issue

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, no problem at all. There is more to the question I am sure, but as this addresses all points, I'm just doing my job :)

Comment: @mplungjan, it is still showing down vote on my answer,

Comment: so delete it - it is answer 3 more times and yours have the least explanation. I cannot remove the downvote unless edited

Comment: @AndyHolmes `$('#mylink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = 'newURL.php'; 
});` saves a line

Comment: @mplungjan very true, the additional set isn't required if this is your desired functionality OP :)

Answer (score 0):

use  `e.preventDefault()` on click on link

```js
$('#mylink').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    $('#mylink').attr('href','newURL.php');
     console.log("NEW LINK ="+$('#mylink').attr('href'));
     window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="" id=mylink>click</a>
```

Comment: What use would that be. You change the HREF and then what?

Comment: @ mplungjan  , see now answer updated

Comment: The page will change, the link will be gone

Comment: @ mplungjan  , then what do you want

Comment: I want OP to ask a proper question and not post an X/Y problem

Comment: then that is not my problem , you discoureging everybody by downvoting answer

Comment: Because you all answered the same. We should fix the actual problem, not just answer questions in my opinion - anyway, removed my downvote